# Converting Excel into a website?

Tags: web-apps, web-development, microsoft-excel

I need to build a tool which will take a list of items (comma separated), look these items up in a separate sheet/database and show the information about each of the items listed. I can make this in Excel (vlookups), and probably Access, but ideally would like the make this available wider - through a website, app, or similar.

How difficult would this be? And where do I start??? I'm hoping it’s not too difficult, but willing to learn new skills to be able to achieve it.

Any advice really appreciated. As I said, I can make this work in Excel but I don’t know where to start in converting this to an online version.

Thanks!
P

Comment: How much work do you want to put into it?  PHP is a programming language you can code everything with are you ok with that?  Also PHP has a dozen frameworks like laveral to do to some of the under the hood stuff for you.  Also phpRAD in another kind of tool you might be interested in.

Comment: Thanks for the response @cybernard It looks like PHP is what I need then. I’ve not experience but willing to learn! Any advice on where to start, other than typing PHP into Google which I will be doing shortly....

Answer (score 0):

This is not a trivial task, but once done the easy of use for updating and managing it should make it worth the effort.

I had purchased an online, watch the videos style class, that covered 7 different frameworks, but it copyrighted so I can't post any of it.

First you need to install PHP,database, and a webserver.

Luckily there are open source version of all of these.

1. Apache webserver
2. php
3. Mariadb
4. Lavarel or similar framework
   You will need to import the data to be looked up into the database.
5. create a database
6. create a table with column names and data types.
   Tools like adminer and phpMywebadmin Give you a graphical interface
7. the database has a built in tool to read CSV and similiar into the table.
   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/how-to-quickly-insert-data-into-mariadb/
   https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/load-data-infile/

All of these have windows and linux version.

I would suggest you start learning a framework like Lavarel because it takes care of most of the "under the hood" work for you.  Do you want to worry about doing prepare statements and other security issues, of COURSE NOT! Lucky the framework usually handles all of this for you.

The website has a set of installation instructions.

Now with everything installed and ready you can now use the framework to make your website look any way you want.

The get_csv() command will take whatever the user enters that is comma separated and places it into an array.

```
<?php
$Data = str_getcsv($CsvString, "\n"); //parse the rows
foreach($Data as &$Row) $Row = $userdata = array_combine(str_getcsv($Row, ";"), $userdata); ; //parse the items in rows 

foreach ($data as $value) {
    //sql database query goes here, but is simplified by using a framework.
    // send the data out to a view
}
```

?>